# Xcode - How to know which classes used or imported a certain class?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

For example, I have `Class A` (both header and cpp file), how do I know which cpp files or header files used `Class A`?

In Eclipse, I can `Open Call Hierarchy` to do this.

How do I do this in Xcode?

Comment: Ahh, I used Find Selected Text in Workspace. zZz

Answer (score 1):

As convenient as this feature might be, unfortunately as of **Xcode 4.3**, this feature is still **NOT present**.

Comment: Aww..too bad, but it's still fine using "Find Selected Text in Workspace", it will make a thorough search :D

Comment: @Coola Yep, true; that's the same one I myself am using... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode **Related Items** menu can be accessed by clicking the "four squares" icon at the editor's top left, or pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>

The Related Items menu includes **Included By**, where you can see all of the other classes that include this class.

[image: Included By menu in Xcode]